# How to flush custom route?

Tags: networking, macos, terminal, routing

I am on MacOS system and after running some script, I had some garbage in my route table shown below:

```
27.123.232/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
36.255.220/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
43.246.112/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
45.114.108/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
45.122.96/21       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
52.80/16           172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
52.81/16           172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
52.82/15           172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
101.36/17          172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
101.36.128/17      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.9.192/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.14.32/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.27.184/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.27.212/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.35.180/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.68.64/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.68.88/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.68.100/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.68.128/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.68.192/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.69.16/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.69.116/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.69.132/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.69.152/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.69.212/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.70.8/22        172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.70.148/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.70.184/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.70.220/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.70.224/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.70.236/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.70.252/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71/22          172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.32/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.48/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.68/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.72/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.80/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.84/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.88/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.120/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.124/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.128/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.144/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.196/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.200/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.71.232/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.12/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.16/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.20/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.24/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.28/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.32/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.36/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.40/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.44/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.48/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.52/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.112/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.116/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.120/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.124/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.128/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.132/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.144/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.148/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.164/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.172/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.180/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.224/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.228/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.232/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.236/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.240/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.244/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.248/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.72.252/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73/22          172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.4/22        172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.8/22        172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.12/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.16/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.20/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.24/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.28/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.48/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.88/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.96/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.116/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.120/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.128/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.132/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.136/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.140/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.144/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.168/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.176/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.204/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.208/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.240/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.244/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.73.248/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.24/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.28/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.32/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.36/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.40/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.44/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.48/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.56/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.60/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.80/22       172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.124/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.148/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.152/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
103.74.156/22      172.19.25.254      UGSc            0        0     en0
```

And more...obviously. So it becomes clear that I cannot remove them by typing `route delete ...`. I tried route flush and it doesn't work. Is there a way to remove them all at once?

I was able to output all the IPs needed to be removed by using `netstat -nr | grep 172.19.25.254 | awk '{print$1}'` but I don't know what to do next...

Comment: Alternatively use `ip route flush`. See more:: https://ss64.com/bash/ip-route.html

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, you just need to issue `sudo route -n flush` several times. Try 4 or 5 times. Then bring the network interface down and back up, either by disabling/re-enabling in System Preferences, or issuing:

`sudo ifconfig en0 down`

and then:

`sudo ifconfig en0 up`